# Using the chromatic number to compute an optimal coloring

Tags: graphs, polynomial-time, colorings

Suppose we are given a graph $G$ of order $n$ and a black box that can efficiently (polynomial time) compute the chromatic number $\chi(G)$. I am curious to hear how would one go about in order to construct a proper coloring of $G$, more precisely

> Find an efficient algorithm (polynomial time) to construct a proper coloring of $G$ provided that you can efficiently compute the chromatic number.

Does anybody see a simple algorithm for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as possible, add edges to $G$ which do not increase the chromatic number. You should get a complete multipartite graph which corresponds to an optimal coloring.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you elaborate a bit? I don't see how adding new edges (and turning this graph into a multigraph) assists in finding the coloring.

Comment: Since this is likely a homework exercise, I'd rather not give complete details.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus without knowing the algorithm which produced the chromatic number, how can you detect which edges to add? The chromatic number is known and it could be found in polynomial time is known. The unknown is the color assignment. I don't think its straight-forward.

Comment: I beg to differ.